# How to make the first accordion (FAQ) open and the rest closed in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have created dynamic FAQ plugin and its working well. But I have an issue of how to make first accordion tab open using bootstrap class `show` and the rest closed by using WordPress `the_ID();` function.

```
<?php
    $mypost = array( 'post_type' => 'faqs', );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $mypost );
    ?>
   <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();?>
        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
        <div class="accordion" id="accordionPanelsStayOpenExample">
          <div class="accordion-item">
            <h2 class="accordion-header" id="panelsStayOpen-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
              <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#panelsStayOpen-collapse<?php the_ID(); ?>" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="panelsStayOpen-collapse<?php the_ID(); ?>">
              <?php the_title(); ?>
              </button>
            </h2>
            <div id="panelsStayOpen-collapse<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="panelsStayOpen-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
              <div class="accordion-body">
                <strong><?php the_content(); ?>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </article>
 
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

so the first tab should always be

```
 <div id="panelsStayOpen-collapse<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="panelsStayOpen-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
```

and the rest

```
 <div id="panelsStayOpen-collapse<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="panelsStayOpen-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that your `<div class="accordion"...>` items need unique IDs, like this:

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordionPanelsStayOpenExample-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
```

But to your main point: to programmatically make the first panel have a class of "collapse show" and subsequent ones have a class of just "collapse", keep track of which one you're up to via a counter (in my case `$i`) and selectively add "show" on all but the first:

```
<div id="panelsStayOpen-collapse<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="accordion-collapse collapse <?php if ($i++) { ?>show<?php } ?>" aria-labelledby="panelsStayOpen-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
```

So your entire code would become:

```
<?php
    $mypost = array( 'post_type' => 'faqs', );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $mypost );
    $i = 0;
    ?>
   <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();?>
        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
        <div class="accordion" id="accordionPanelsStayOpenExample-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
          <div class="accordion-item">
            <h2 class="accordion-header" id="panelsStayOpen-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
              <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#panelsStayOpen-collapse<?php the_ID(); ?>" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="panelsStayOpen-collapse<?php the_ID(); ?>">
              <?php the_title(); ?>
              </button>
            </h2>
            <div id="panelsStayOpen-collapse<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="accordion-collapse collapse <?php if ($i++) { ?>show<?php } ?>" aria-labelledby="panelsStayOpen-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
              <div class="accordion-body">
                <strong><?php the_content(); ?>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </article>
 
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```